# React json check if empty?

Tags: reactjs

I'm making my last project for school. I want to check for `if "{item.fields.haaksoort}"` is empty. When this is empty I want nothing to happen. Else post `"<p>haaksoort: {item.fields.haaksoort}</p>"`.

Sidenote: I can display `"<p>haaksoort: {item.fields.haaksoort}</p>"` and the connection is right.

Comment: What is `haaksoort`? Array, object, string?

Comment: haaksoort is just a word inside a <p>Haaksoort:</p>, Dutch for hooktype.

Comment: if the object you're trying to render is empty, it will generate an error with react, best course for you here is to check if its empty before you render the results.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator

Comment: you can add a middleware isEmpty like the following :

exports.isEmpty = (string)=> {
    if (string.trim() === "") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false
    } 
}

Comment: i put this in; {item.fields.haaksoort}.isEmpty = (string)=> { if (string.trim() === "") { return true; } else { return false } } but it gives a error. but i dont see what to do with this code.

Comment: If possible, please add the code snippet or json format from where u r trying to fetch it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern to check for empty variables.  If the field has a value then your `<p>` will render.  If `haaksort` doesn't exist on `item.fields` or the value of `haaksort` is undefined then the `<p>` won't render.

`{item.fields.haaksoort && (<p>haaksoort: {item.fields.haaksoort}</p>)}`

A couple of notes on this though:

- `item` and `fields` must also exist.
- This will not yield the desired result if `haaksoort` is the empty string

If you need to do checking on the above conditions then a middleware function like mentioned in the question comment will best serve you.  Then you can do something like this in your render code:

`{isEmpty(item.fields.haaksoort) ? '' : (<p>haaksoort: {item.fields.haaksoort}</p>)`

Note that this is a simplistic example of a call to a middleware function that assumes that `item` exists with a property `fields` that also exists.

Comment: If you don't want to check if item and fields exist, you can use optional chaining operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Yes, and I did consider including this (actually forgot to go back and mention it).  However I have only moderate success with this.  While I admit I may have to go back and revisit the feature, I had cross-browser support issues with it  as well as other inconsistencies.  To the point of just writing a middleware function to address it.

Comment: but we're talking about a React app, where transpilation is included if bootstrapped with CRA.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the below function to check obj is empty. Here what

> Object.keys

does is that, it returns the keys of the objects attributes, so if the length of the keys is 0 we can deduce that the object is empty.

```
function checkIfJSONisEmpty(obj){
    return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
}
```